# Need precision about an example in a book about bayesian filters

Tags: bayesian, filter

My question is about the example here : https://github.com/w407022008/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/02-Discrete-Bayes.ipynb#Adding-Uncertainty-to-the-Prediction paragraph : *Integrating Measurements and Movement Updates*.

and

https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/03-Gaussians.ipynb paragraph *Bayes Theorem*

The Author says that if the sensor measure a position $z$, his belief is that $p(x<z-10) = p(z+10 \le x) = 0.1%$ and  $p(z-10 \le x < z+10) = 0.8$

Later, when he illustrates it with the Bayes' Theorem, then he says that $p(z|x)$ is the likelihood of the measurement, and use the same distribution as previously defined to model it.

However something bothers me : from how he describe his belief in the sensor, I understand that, "given" (could be rephrased by "wknowing ?) a measurement `z` of x, he gives the probability of x lying in intervals. I feel more like it's the description of a general of $p(x|z)$ without any prior knowledge ?

What is actually $p(z|x)$ (and the other terms) in the formulation of the Bayes' Theorem the author give ?

I think I'm wrong but I would like to know where, and why ?

Answer (score 0):

Bayes theorem says

$$\text{posterior}\sim \frac{\text{prior}\cdot{\text{likelihood}}}{\text{evidence}}$$

The posterior, the $z$ you are trying to infer is $p(z|x)$. The prior is $p(z)$, and the likelihood is $p(x|z)$.

The point is that it is easier to estimate the likelihood, that is, what the sensor will say if you know the position, and you can give a reasonable prior, but it is hard to write down immediately what the position is given the sensor.